# Clock hands are getting restored at every interval of time in clock

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

Here is the code for an analog clock. Please check my code and help me with a solution....

http://jsfiddle.net/3rSQE/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...you need to clear the canvas *every* time you draw to it.

In this case, you can't even really do the dirty-rectangle solutions without working out a blitting system, like the old-school games.

So you need to call ctx.clearRect() on every single call to clock().
...not just the call to analog();

The other solution is to have two canvases, position them on top of one another with CSS, and have one hold the clock image, and have the other constantly draw and clear and redraw the arms.

Answer (score -1):

based on [THIS](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/script-context2d-scripts-clock-js.html) example, i do [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/DgRTu/) that seem to work, check difference with your code.